# Check whether there is an Network connection available on pure dart

Tags: networking, dart

Is there a way in dart to get notified (listen to) **when the network disconnecting** and do action only if it off?.

I do not want to check internet connection so no need for pinging google.com (connection to router without internet is still good).

Searching for simple way that interact with the network interfaces of the device and listen to change or return True/False about the network state.

In worse case I can use `Process.run(...)` with bash commend but this ugly fix.

**No flutter** here only **pure dart** (dart Console Application).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the program on linux you can use bash commend like this

```
  //  Check if connected to network, if there is a connection than return network name
  Future<String> getConnectedNetworkName() async {
    return await Process.run('iwgetid',
        ['-r']).then((ProcessResult results) {
      print(results.stdout.toString());
      return results.stdout.toString().replaceAll('\n', '');
    });
  }
```

This will return network name even if the network does not connected to the internet